# KeyCloak 22.0.1 fresh download on macOS produces error

Tags: keycloak

I just downloaded KeyCloak 22.0.1 on a mac with Ventura 13.4.1. I'm using java 17. I unpacked the
zip file, changed into the directory and startet a:

```bash
bin/kc.sh start-dev
```

KeyCloak starts build and stops with the error:

```bash
2023-07-25 13:33:12,995 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@623e088f

2023-07-25 13:33:12,995 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@623e088f

ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
ERROR: Name is too long
```

The same procedure with KeyCloak 21.1.1 works fine. What am i doing wrong?

I tried KC Version 21.1.1 with the same setup and everything works fine.

The same with Version 22.0.1 creates the error.